# Trouble with multiple firebase image upload with progress

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, promise, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload multiple images to firebase at once. It is doing that, but the returned url array of those cloud image links are too late since the post is already being sent with an empty array. Here is my code:

```
// uploading media files using promises
  async uploadMedia(mediaFile: string){
      const extension = mediaFile.split('.')[mediaFile.split('.').length - 1];
      const mediaFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000)}.${extension}`;
      this.uploadProgress = 0;
      const response = await fetch(mediaFile);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const storageRef = storage.ref(`${mediaFileName}`).put(blob);
      return storageRef.on(`state_changed`,snapshot=>{
        this.uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes);
      }, error=>{
        this.error = error.message;
        this.submitting = false;
        this.uploadingMedia = false;
        return;
      },
      async () => {
        // check whether the media is an image or a video and add to correct arrays
        if(extension == "png" || extension == "jpg"){
          return storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(async (url)=>{
            this.firebaseImageUrls = [...this.firebaseImageUrls, url];
            return;
          });
        }
        else{
          return storageRef.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(async (url)=>{
            this.firebaseVideoUrls = [...this.firebaseVideoUrls, url];
            return;
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Where everything is being called:

```
await Promise.all(this.props.store.selectedImagesArray.map(async (file:string) => {
        await this.uploadMedia(file);
      }))
this.submitPost(); // this submits everything with the firebaseImageUrls
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to make a promise and resolve the promise for each upload task and then loop through all the files doing this. Then when all the files are completely uploaded and the loop is completed, then I can submit the post with the files that are in firebaseImageUrls.

```
async uploadMedia(mediaFile: string){
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      //making the uploading task for one file
      const extension = mediaFile.split('.')[mediaFile.split('.').length - 1];
      const mediaFileName = `${Math.round(Math.random()*100000000000)}.${extension}`;
      const response = await fetch(mediaFile);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      const storageRef = storage.ref(`${mediaFileName}`);
      const task = storageRef.put(blob);

      task.on(`state_changed`,snapshot=>{
        this.uploadProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes);
      }, error=>{
        this.error = error.message;
        this.submitting = false;
        this.uploadingMedia = false;
        return;
      },
      async () => {
        if(extension == "png" || extension == "jpg"){
          task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url:any)=>{
            console.log(url);
            resolve(url);
          });
        }
        else{
          task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url:any)=>{
            console.log(url);
            resolve(url);
          });
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

The loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.props.store.selectedImagesArray.length; i++){
        const imageUrl = await this.uploadMedia(this.props.store.selectedImagesArray[i]);
        this.firebaseImageUrls = [...this.firebaseImageUrls, imageUrl];
}
this.submitPost();
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that `storageRef.on()` does not return a promise. It just registers the handlers. I'm not an expert on firebase. Maybe the `put(blob)` returns a promise that you can use.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But then I have no clue how to represent the progress of the image uploads then since I have to reference the .put(blob). This works btw, i just need the uploading status as well.